# Matching of strings with special characters

Tags: c++, string

I need to generate a string that can match another both containing special characters. I wrote what I thought would be a simple method, but so far nothing has given me a successful match.

I know that specials characters in c++ are preceded with a "\". Per example a single quote would be written as "\'".

```
string json_string(const string& incoming_str)
{
    string str = "\\\"" + incoming_str + "\\\"";
    return str;
}
```

And this is the string I have to compare to:

```
bool comp = json_string("hello world") == "\"hello world\"";
```

I can see in the cout stream that in fact I'm generating the string as needed but the comparison still gives a `false` value.

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The string `"\"hello world\""` is not equal to `"\\\"hello world\\\""`.

Comment: `"\\\"" + incoming_str + "\\\""` turns into `\"incoming_str\"`, while `"\"hello world\""` only turns into `"hello world"`. Instead of `string str = "\\\"" + incoming_str + "\\\"";` try `string str = "\"" + incoming_str + "\"";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to filter one string and compare this filtered string. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

std::string filterBy(std::string unfiltered, std::string specialChars)
{
    std::string filtered;

    std::copy_if(unfiltered.begin(), unfiltered.end(),
              std::back_inserter(filtered), [&specialChars](char c){return specialChars.find(c) == -1;});

    return filtered;
}

int main() {
    std::string specialChars = "\"";
    std::string string1 = "test";
    std::string string2 = "\"test\"";

    std::cout << (string1 == filterBy(string2, specialChars) ? "match" : "no match");

    return 0;
}
```

Output is `match`. This code also works if you add an arbitrary number of characters to `specialChars`.

If both strings contain special characters, you can also put `string1` through the `filterBy` function. Then, something like:

```
"\"hello \" world \"" == "\"hello world "
```

will also match.

If the comparison is performance-critical, you might also have a comparison that uses two iterators, getting a comparison complexity of log(N+M), where N and M are the sizes of the two strings, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool comp = json_string("hello world") == "\"hello world\"";
```

This will definitely yield false. You are creating string `\"hello world\"` by `json_string("hello world")` but comparing it to `"hello world"`

The problem is here:

```
 string str = "\\\"" + incoming_str + "\\\"";
```

In your first string literal of str, the first character backlash that you’re assuming to be treated like escape character is not actually being treated an escape character, rather just a backslash in your string literal. You do the same in your last string literal.

**Do this**:

```
string str = "\"" + incoming_str + "\"";
```

Comment: I see your point. I thought the OP was expecting jason_string work like a string object. Corrected!

Answer (score 0):

In C++ string *literals* are delimited by quotes.

Then the problem arises: How can I define a string literal that does *itself* contain quotes? In Python (for comparison), this can get easy (but there are other drawbacks with this approach not of interest here): `'a string with " (quote)'`.

C++ doesn't have this alternative string representation<sup>1</sup>, instead, you are limited to using escape sequences (which are available in Python, too – just for completeness...): Within a string (or character) literal (but nowhere else!), the sequence `\"` will be replaced by a single quote in the resulting string.

So `"\"hello world\""` defined as character array would be:

```
{ '"', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '"', 0 };
```

Note that now the escape character is not necessary...

Within your `json_string` function, you append additional backslashes, though:

```
"\\\""
{ '\', '"', 0 }
//^^^
```

Note that I wrote `'\'` just for illustration! How would you define single quote? By escaping again! `'\''` – but now you need to escape the escape character, too, so a single backslash actually needs to be written as `'\\'` here (wheras in comparison, you don't have to escape the single quote in a string literal: `"i am 'singly quoted'"` – just as you didn't have to escape the double quote in the character literal).

As JSON uses double quotes for strings, too, you'd most likely want to change your function:

```
return "\"" + incoming_str + "\"";
```

or even much simpler:

```
return '"' + incoming_str + '"';
```

Now

```
json_string("hello world") == "\"hello world\""
```

would yield true...

<sup>1</sup> Side note (stolen from answer deleted in the meanwhile): Since C++11, there are [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), too. Using these, you don't have to escape either.